# SQL Working with Bit values to get either true or false

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL table that has a bit column named "Split".

I need to create a stored procedure that receives a parameter named WithSplit of type bit.

If WithSplit is false then I need to get all the records that have the  "Split" column equal to false.
If WithSplit is true, then  I need to get the records having the "Split" column value either true or false.

That is , if WithSplit is false then get only the records where split=withsplit, else get all records.

How should this be achieved?

Comment: `where @withsplit = 1 or (@withsplit = 0 and Split = 0)`

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer:

```
 (Split  = @WithSplit or @WithSplit =  case when @WithSplit =1 then 1  end)
```